# jQuery selectionBox plugin - set default text to selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I'm currently using this plugin called Selection Box [(link to plugin on Github),](https://github.com/dfadler/jquery.selectionBox) to style a select drop-down.

The problem I have and haven't solved yet is the fact that I'd like the default text to be that of the selected option (set by attribute selected="selected" on the select option).

**[Here is a link to a demo of the plugin.](http://dfadler.github.io/jquery.selectionBox/)**

In this example, the default text is used, "Select an Option".  None of the options have been set as selected in the example, but if one of the options was set to selected, I'd like for the text of that option to show up (basically like a regular select box would behave).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!  I poked into the JS a bit but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a fix by updating the plugin setDefaultText function to the following:

```
        setDefaultText: function() {
           //this.$current.text(this.options.defaultText);
            this.$current.text(this.$el.find('option:selected').text());

            return this;
        },
```